# How do I stop the debugger in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I would like to interact with the page I am building with the console open.  Unfortunately, if I trigger an event on my page the Dev Tools switches from "Console" to "Sources" and says "paused in debugger." It's driving me bananas. Is there a way to deactivate it?

[image: Debugger activates itself anytime I interact with my page]

Comment: Try removing your Breakpoints (visible in the right panel) and it should work as normal.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. This one asks how to disable breakpoints while the linked one are about pause on exception. The two has different solutions.

Answer (score 19):

### How to deactivate breakpoints

Just press Ctrl + F8. Alternatively you can click the related button next to the buttons controlling the debugger.

[image: Deactivate breakpoints inside devtools]

This way the execution won't stop. It is especially useful when you try to inspect websites not under your control that left breakpoints (`debugger` command) in the source code, that might have been done intentionally to prevent you from doing said inspection.

Answer (score 9):

You likely have a Breakpoint set on an Event. To remove it:

1. Open Debugger (F12)
2. Click on the Sources Tab
3. Click on the Event Listeners Breakpoints accordion dropdown (on the right)
4. Unselect (untick) each event that you do NOT want to break on.

Answer (score 2):

Check your DOM, XHR and Event Listener breakpoints, and ensure they're unchecked/inactive.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the debugger in Chrome, the circled icon should be deactivated (which will turn it grey colored): [image: Example of icon]